# Laravel 5.3 photo upload with plupload directory related issue

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, plupload

I have recently migrated my code into laravel. I have faced problem with file upload using plupload with laravel. In pluploaded file is uploaded to server before form submitting. After uploaded file succesfully, file path is put in hidden input field.
My Upload Code is given below.

```
public function photo(){
  $target_file = "";
  $this->target_dir = base_path() ."/uploads/";
  if($_FILES['file']['name']){
     $filename = AppUtils::get_new_filename($this->ext);
     $filename = "photo_" . $filename;
     $target_file = $this->target_dir . $filename;
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target_file);
     $photo = $this->target_dir . $filename;
     echo $photo;
     die();
   }
   else{
     AppUtils::fail();
   }
}
```

Problem is without using base_path() in $target_dir, file is not uploaded properly. But using base_path() preview image not actual location.
For example, After uploading photo output will be `/var/www/htm/lar/uploads/xyz.jpg` 
But in preview image path shows : `http://example.com/lar/var/www/html/lar/uploads/xyz.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function photo(){
  $target_file = "";
  $this->target_dir = "/uploads/";
  if($_FILES['file']['name']){
     $filename = AppUtils::get_new_filename($this->ext);
     $filename = "photo_" . $filename;
     $target_file = base_path() . $this->target_dir . $filename;
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target_file);
     $photo = $this->target_dir . $filename;
     echo $photo;
     die();
   }
   else{
     AppUtils::fail();
   }
}
```

`base_path()` should only be used for the upload location.